# Transformar String em Array de elementos

Tags: javascript, array, string

já olhei vários exemplos na NET mas não estou conseguindo resolver essa situação. 
Agradeço se alguém puder ajudar.

Eu preciso converter uma string em um Array com elementos, eu vou receber essa string de um banco de dados e com base nela preciso montar o Array.

Quando eu carrego o Array com valores fixos ele monta direitinho o que eu preciso como pode ser visto no print do Debug abaixo, é exatamente dessa forma que eu preciso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando eu monto usando os valores (string) que peguei do Banco não está montando da mesma forma do exemplo da figura acima.

Ele monta dessa forma..
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu montei um exemplo no https://codepen.io/egameiro/pen/JqqPxW para poder testar.

Segue o código completo que estou usando.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const circles = [{
  id: '1',
  x: 40,
  y: 40,
  radius: 5,
  color: 'rgb(255,0,0)'
}, {
  id: '2',
  x: 100,
  y: 70,
  radius: 5,
  color: 'rgb(0,0,255)'
}, {
  id: '3',
  x: 160,
  y: 100,
  radius: 5,
  color: 'rgb(0,255,0)'
}];

circles.forEach(circle => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(circle.x, circle.y, circle.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = circle.color;
  ctx.fill();
});

var bb = document.getElementById("LinhaPontos").value
const circles2 = [bb];
var aa = 0;

const novaArray = circles2.map(Object.values);
var bb = 0;
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="LinhaPontos" class="btn btn-info " size="40" value="{id: '1', x: 40, y: 40, radius: 5, color: 'rgb(255,0,0)'}" />
</div>

<canvas id="canvas" width="650" height="650" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
```

Comment: E qual seria a string?

Comment: Já tentou `circles2.map(circle => Object.values(JSON.parse(circle)))` ?

Comment: Mas a informação que está no `value` era para 1 ponto ? e os outros ? Para o formato que está a inserir o ideal é interpretar como JSON.

Comment: Oi Isac a informação que está no value é para um ponto. So coloquei como exemplo, mas normalmente terão vários pontos.

Comment: user140828.. tentei e não deu certo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que você precisa de duas coisas:

Primeiro mudar a forma que escreve os dados, utilize a forma de JSON:

```
{"id": "1", "x": 40, "y": 40, "radius": 5, "color": "rgb(255,0,0)"}
```

atributos e string com aspas duplas ";

E depois quando recuperar esta string, usar o `JSON.parse()` para converter em um objeto;

Resultado final:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const circles = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("LinhaPontos").value);
    
  circles.forEach(circle => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(circle.x, circle.y, circle.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = circle.color;
  ctx.fill();
});
```

```html
<div>
 <input type="text" id="LinhaPontos" class="btn btn-info " size="40" value='[{"id":"1","x":40,"y":40,"radius":5,"color":"rgb(255,0,0)"},{"id":"2","x":100,"y":70,"radius":5,"color":"rgb(0,0,255)"},{"id":"3","x":160,"y":100,"radius":5,"color":"rgb(0,255,0)"}]'  />
</div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="650" height="650" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado JDuwe era exatamente isso que eu precisava.

Answer (score 0):

Como você quer o array ?

pode tentar usar o split;

exemplo:

```
var string = 'oi';

var array = string.split('');
```

ou se estiver com virgula só usar a virgula no split e ele faz um array da string.